# Why Async function returning System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await

I have a VB.NET function as below:

```
Public Shared Async Function GetIdDoc() As Task(Of String)
    Dim result As String = ""
    'Dim Uri As String = "http://localhost:53917/api/Documenti/GetNextIdDocumenti"
    Dim Uri As String = apiUri & ApiEndPoints.GetNextIdDocumenti

    Using client = New HttpClient()
        Using response = Await client.GetAsync(Uri)
            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim DocumentiIDJsonString = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                result = DocumentiIDJsonString.ToString()

            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

I'm trying to return the Document ID from the DB but I'm getting

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

Where actually it should return "2". Please help me on this: what am I doing wrong with this function?

**Update**

here is the function called:

```
 txtIDDoc_Detail.Text = ApiData.GetIdDoc().ToString()
```

But inside the textbox I'm getting the above text. thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to also show the code where the function is called.

Comment: Please check my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably rename `GetIdDoc` to `GetIdDocAsync` to follow the generally recommended pattern for async methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm from C# but should work the same. In newer .Net Versions (>= 4.5) async/await is implemented. So if a method is marked as async and returns a Task (which should always be the case), you need to await it. This implicate that you have to mark your Method as async too. So your call should look like this:

```
txtIDDoc_Detail.Text = await ApiData.GetIdDoc();
```

The await waits till the long running Task is ready and returns it's inner value. All async Methods should return Task. If the Method is void it would be Task. Else it could be `Task<int>` or any other type. So await it and you can keep running ;)

Comment: Or `txtIDDoc_Detail.Text = ApiData.GetIdDoc.Result` if you want to run it synchronously (for whatever reason).

Comment: @BradleyUffner - `ApiData.GetIdDoc.Result` can cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

@Sebi gives a great explanation of how to properly use `async` and `await` in this case, but I'm going to expand on exactly *why* you are getting the result that you see.

```
 txtIDDoc_Detail.Text = ApiData.GetIdDoc().ToString()
```

Is returning

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

Because you are calling `.ToString` on the **instance of the Task** `Task(Of String)`, not the actual result.  Types that don't override `.ToString` inherit the behavior of `Object`, which just returns the name of the type as a string.

You probably want this (asynchronous call):

```
txtIDDoc_Detail.Text = await ApiData.GetIdDoc()
```

Or this (synchronous call):

```
txtIDDoc_Detail.Text = ApiData.GetIdDoc().Result
```

Either of these calls will actually result of the task after it has completed.

Comment: `ApiData.GetIdDoc().Result ` can cause a deadlock, check this for more information: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: It will cause a deadlock if the GetIdDoc(); Method returns a result in MainThread. Because the Method want to return it while Result try to access it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my issue.