# Getting response out of httpclient

Tags: c#, httpresponse, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use a WEB API for a personal learning project. The code is successful when trying to get a response from the server, but I can't get the body out of the response.

I am supposed to be getting something like:

```
{
"start_time": "2017-12-21T11:03:52Z",
"players": 27721,
"server_version": "1223575"
}
```

but I'm getting this instead:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,X-User-Agent
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type,Warning,X-Pages,X-ESI-Error-Limit-Remain,X-ESI-Error-Limit-Reset
  Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Esi-Error-Limit-Remain: 100
  X-Esi-Error-Limit-Reset: 54
  Alt-Svc: clear
  Cache-Control: public
  Date: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 20:38:06 GMT
  Via: 1.1 google
  Content-Length: 80
  Content-Type: application/json
  Expires: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 20:38:34 GMT
  Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 20:38:04 GMT
}
```

Here's my code:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            GetTaskAsync("status/?datasource=tranquility").Wait();
        }

        static async Task GetTaskAsync(String endpoint)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + endpoint);         
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        GetTaskAsync("status/?datasource=tranquility").Wait();
    }

    static async Task GetTaskAsync(String endpoint)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + endpoint);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't think that will work if `GetTaskAsync` doesn't return anything.

Comment: This worked too. Thanks a lot. I was missing the await for the 'var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();' line.

Comment: It does work. Interesting. How can you wait on a Task that isn't even returned? Now I have something to look into.

Comment: @Crowcoder: `async` functions return `Task` (as it says in the return type).  You can `await` a non-generic `Task` with no value.

Comment: @SLaks thanks, duh. 6 a.m. deployment, I need stop try think now.

Answer (score 1):

Call `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to read the body from the response.

Comment: This worked, but I'm getting 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]' I found that I had to await it in another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40292114/9128665