# System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[<myType>] being returned

Tags: c#, async-await

This may seem like a duplicate of [Why Async function returning System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291526/why-async-function-returning-system-threading-tasks-task1system-string) but I am doing the things suggested in the Answers there but to no avail.

I'm running a Console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...

        var details = CallRestMethodAsync(url, filterObj);
        Console.Write(details);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static async Task<NotificationEvents> CallRestMethodAsync(string url, FilterPager filterPager = null)
    {
         ...
         var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationEvents>(result, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    }
```

When I put a break-point on the last line of `CallRestMethodAsync` and examine `result`, I find it DOES contain the object expected. And JsonConvert does not  throw an error.

But the output I get is:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[NotificationsHandler.NotificationEvents]
```

Update (4/30/2019, 11:09 CT):
After accepting @Martin Brown's answer, I realized that I was (stupidly) expecting to see a stringified instance of my type output on the Console. Of course that wouldn't work. What I needed to do inside `Main` was :
`var details = (CallRestMethodAsync(url, filterObj)).Result; // to force the Task to resolve to my type
            foreach (var result in details.Results) // Results being a (array) property
                Console.Write(details.Results[0].EventDate); // EventDate being a prop that the Console could actually output`

Comment: Yes? Your method returns a task? You need to await the task to get the results.

Comment: I think you might benefit from reading this Question + especially all the Answers given: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9208921/1220550

Comment: What exactly are you expecting it to output?

Comment: @MartinBrown Gosh, I just realized I was expecting it to output the stringified instance of the type. I think I've been working with javascript too long!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CallRestMethodAsync` method returns a `Task<NotificationEvents>` rather than the `NotificationEvents` expected. You can set your `Main` method to `await` the result of `CallRestMethodAsync` like this:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    var details = await CallRestMethodAsync(url, filterObj);
    Console.Write(details);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

If you are using an older version of .net you may not be able to create an async main method. In that case you will need to get the `Result` of the task like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...

    var details = CallRestMethodAsync(url, filterObj);
    Console.Write(details.Result);
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: When I try turning the Main method async, VS doesn't complain until compilation, with this error: `CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

Comment: I am not able to create an async Main method. (.net 4.6) and I did actually try `.Result` on details earlier (though I read something about it possibly causing blocking). However, doing that produced `NotificationsHandler.NotificationEvents` in the console

Comment: async main was introduced in C# 7. I'm not sure which version of .net that requires but I expect 4.6 isn't high enough. If you take a look in your project's properties in visual studio it will tell you what C# versions you can use under Build/Advanced.

Comment: NotificationsHandler.NotificationEvents is the default return value of ToString() for the NotificationEvents class. This is what Console.Write is outputting. If you want something else you will need to use properties or method calls to select something else off that object.

Comment: I know that it's returning the default `.ToString()` output but shouldn't it be returning the instance instead?
Also, I have Langauge Version set to:  `C# latest major version` in Advanced Build Settings.

Comment: No, it won't return the instance instead. Console.WriteLine takes a string not a NotificationEvents. C# tries to convert the NotificationEvents instance into a string by calling the instance's ToString() method (a method all objects have).

Comment: In my defense, the `NotificationEvents` type has a property called `Result` which threw me off. I thought I was looking at a Task when I was really looking at the instance of NotificationEvents. :-(

Comment: No worries. It's not the easiest thing to get your head arround.